# Is there a way to view IP addresses that have been assigned, historically, to a single Windows XP workstation?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, security, ip

For example, if a laptop had an IP address of a.b.c.d during period x and then an IP address of a.b.c.e during period y, would it be possible to see both of these addresses in a list somewhere (perhaps in the registry)?

Comment: Who is doing the address assignment, and how?

Comment: Try the event log.

Comment: They are manually assigned at build-time. I have looked in the event log but can't find anything. Any idea what the event ID might be? Thanks.